# How to upload image to S3 using AWSUserFileManager Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-mobilehub

I've managed to setup `AWS` mobile hub and I can now login using my facebook credentials. Basically I just want to upload an image to the S3 bucket using `AWSMobileHubHelper`. I know in `AWS` Mobile hub things work differently to regular S3 upload. We're supposed to use `AWSUserFileManager` instead of the usual setup up `AWScognito` credentials + `S3bucket` etc.

I found this function in their documentation but there is no explanation whatsoever. I assume I can pass my image as `NSData` and the key would be my path "public/aaa". I ran the code everything seems fine. I doesn't even throw an error. But when I go to my S3 bucket,the image isn't there.

My question is: What am i suppose to pass as a key?? There is absolutely no documentation whatsoever on this.

If this is not how to do it? How does `AWSUserFileManager` work?

```
func uploadWithData(data: NSData, forKey key: String) {
    let userFilemanager = AWSUserFileManager.defaultUserFileManager()
    let localContent = userFilemanager.localContentWithData(data, key: key)
    localContent.uploadWithPinOnCompletion(false, progressBlock: {(content: AWSLocalContent?, progress: NSProgress?) -> Void in
        // handle progress here
        }, completionHandler: {(content: AWSContent?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                // handle error here
                print("Error occured in uploading: \(error)")
                return
            }
            // handle successful upload here
    })
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this. Basically, this is correct.

To upload data to a public folder you can simply use the exact function above. while the key = "public/yourFileName"

But if you want to upload to a private folder, you need to add the identityId when you declare the AWSUserFileManager, and the key would be = "private/(identityId!)/yourFileName":

```
func uploadWithData(data: NSData, forKey key: String) {
    let userFilemanager = AWSUserFileManager.defaultUserFileManager().identityId!
    let localContent = userFilemanager.localContentWithData(data, key: key)
    localContent.uploadWithPinOnCompletion(false, progressBlock: {(content: AWSLocalContent?, progress: NSProgress?) -> Void in
        // handle progress here
        }, completionHandler: {(content: AWSContent?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                // handle error here
                print("Error occured in uploading: \(error)")
                return
            }
            // handle successful upload here
    })
}
```